# Run solidity bytecode with ethereumj

Tags: evm, ethereumj

I am a newbie to Ethereum and I would like to run some simple smart contract code written in Solidity locally with my `ethereumj` virtual machine.

I am aware of how to use EVM and `aleth-vm` to run some compiled Solidity binary code. But so far still have no idea how to directly use the `ethereumj` locally. Could anyone shed some lights on it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use attach JavaScript VM on the remix site is much easier I think

https://remix.ethereum.org